# special char in glassfish dont work

Tags: java, rest, google-chrome, glassfish, special-characters

Good morning, I have a problem of special characters in my WS application. Running locally it works normal, but when I do deploy on my hosting server it shows this:

> Teste bem sucedido! Ã‰ um teste de acentuaÃ§Ã£o: Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³Ãº!!!

The correct:

> Teste bem sucedido! É um teste de acentuação: áéíóú!!!

My source code is:

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Path("Test")
    public String getTeste() {
        return "<h1>Teste bem sucedido! É um teste de acentuação: áéíóú!!!</h1>";
    }
```

Where is the problem? In my application WS or in the Glassfish configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is obvious that it is an encoding problem - your file seems to be in UTF-8 but your client somehow tries to display it as 8-Bit Characterset like iso-8859-1.

Since you are talking about a web application and rest, the wrong encoding could take place at several steps.

- Have you specified the right enconding within your web page?
- Have you specified the right enconding when you do the rest request?
- Have compared the settings of your servre instances?

Without further details, it is hard to guess where the problem exactly is.

Comment: Tanks, but don't answer my question. What i have made for fix that?

Comment: Your code is correct. I tried to give some hints where you can look for the problem. If you give further details, I might be able to refine the answer...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.
Hi guys. I solved my problema aplly @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8") before my process. Example:

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML+ ";charset=utf-8")
    @Path("Test")
    public String getTeste() {
        return "<h1>Teste bem sucedido! É um teste de acentuação: áéíóú!!!</h1>";
    }
```

Tanks